# Doppler broadening and Voigt profile

Tags: nuclear-physics, spectroscopy, resonance, neutrons

The shape of an isolated neutron resonance at incident neutron energy, $E_{R}$, can to first-order be represented by the single-level Breit-Wigner (SLBW) formalism, which is equivalent to a Lorentzian with the scale parameter, $\gamma$, equal to half the total resonance width, $\Gamma$:
\begin{equation}
    L(x; \gamma) = \frac{1}{\pi \gamma} \left[ \frac{\gamma^{2}}{(x - x_{0})^{2} + \gamma^{2}} \right] \longrightarrow \sigma(E) = 4 \pi \lambda^{2} g_{J} \frac{\Gamma^{2}/4}{(E - E_{R})^{2} + \Gamma^{2}/4}
\end{equation}
where $\lambda$ is the reduced neutron wavelength and $g_{J}$ is a statistical spin factor.

The Doppler-broadened cross section is given by:
\begin{equation}
    \overline{\sigma}(E) = \frac{1}{\Delta \sqrt{\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dE' \exp \left[ -\left(\frac{E' - E}{\Delta}\right)^{2}\right] \frac{\sqrt{E'}}{\sqrt{E}} \sigma(E')
\end{equation}
where the Doppler width is represented by $\Delta$. The factor of $\sqrt{E}$ can be moved over to the LHS to give:
\begin{equation}
    \sqrt{E} \: \overline{\sigma}(E) = \frac{1}{\Delta \sqrt{\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dE' \exp \left[ -\left(\frac{E' - E}{\Delta}\right)^{2}\right] \sqrt{E'} \: \sigma(E')
\end{equation}

However, I have seen it written that the line-shape of the Doppler-broadened resonance can be written as a Voigt profile (the convolution of a Gaussian with a Lorentzian.)

\begin{equation}
    V(x; \sigma, \gamma) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} G(x'; \sigma) L(x - x'; \gamma)dx'
\end{equation}

But it appears to me that the Doppler broadening is not simply a Gaussian, but also has a factor of $\sqrt{E}$ in the integral. What am I missing?